# Draw dicom raw data in qt

Tags: c++, qt, dicom, itk, gdcm

I'm trying to develop a tool to visualize dicom images
I'm using itk library but i have some problem drawing the data
I'm using gdcm library provided by itk library as a third party lib.

I'm reading the image correctly i retrieved the tags ... but when i retrieve the pixels data using

```
unsigned short buffer* = ImageFileReader<Image<unsigned short,2>>->GetOutput()->getBufferPointer();
```

and i put it in QPixmap or QImage i tried both,Qpixelmap when i do loadData i get false as a return value and using QImage, the app crashes !

Any help ? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this example, http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/ConvertToQImage_8cxx-example.html

Just use gdcm to read the image and convert it to qimage.

Keep in mind that dicom images are not an image format that qt can draw, you need a conversion step.